# Compiler Error CS0120 in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to convert a string which contains a hex code to a color. 
I have the following code:

```
CQ currCQ = new CQ();     
string color_startBorderMC = null;
color_startBorderMC = currCQ._color_MCBorder; //returns string! e.g. #ff00ff
Color _startBorderMC_color = new Color();
_startBorderMC_color = ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(color_startBorderMC); //error
```

If I write an method for getting the Color String I still get the same error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFromString(string)'

The method for getting the color string is this:

```
internal string getMCBorderColor()
{
    return this._color_MCBorder;
}
```

My Object CQ has the following definition:

```
public class CQ
{
    public string   _color_mostcriticallBorder  {set; get; };
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Still the same error `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFromString(string)'` @Nameismy

Comment: Sidenote: [Naming Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Are you referring to System.Drawing.Color or System.Windows.Media.Color?

Comment: System.Drawing.Color - I'm using it in an ASP.NET project. I've forgot to mention it above sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an instance of `ColorConverter` class in order to access the method `ConvertFromString`

```
CQ currCQ = new CQ();     
string color_startBorderMC = null;
color_startBorderMC = currCQ._color_MCBorder; //returns string! e.g. #ff00ff
Color _startBorderMC_color = new Color();
ColorConverter converter = new ColorConverter();//create an instance of ColorConverter.
_startBorderMC_color = converter.ConvertFromString(color_startBorderMC);
```

for more information refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25ds5cb6(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) msdn documentation.